# Change expectation to multi dimensional rather than 1D in nn.crossentropyloss

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, conv-neural-network

My goal is to do multi class image classification in Pytorch using the EMNIST dataset.
As a loss function, I would like to use Multi-Class Cross-Entropy Loss.

Currently, I define my loss function as follows:

```
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
```

I train my model as follows:

```
iter = 0
for epoch in range(num_epochs):
    for i, (images, labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
        
        # Add a single channel dimension
        # From: [batch_size, height, width]
        # To: [batch_size, 1, height, width]
        images = images.unsqueeze(1)

        # Forward pass to get output/logits
        outputs = model(images)
        
        # Clear gradients w.r.t. parameters
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        
        # Forward pass to get output/logits
        outputs = model(images)

        # Calculate Loss: softmax --> cross entropy loss
        loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
        
        # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters
        loss.backward()
        
        # Updating parameters
        optimizer.step()
        
        iter += 1
        
        if iter % 500 == 0:
            # Calculate Accuracy         
            correct = 0
            total = 0
            # Iterate through test dataset
            for images, labels in test_loader:
               
                images = images.unsqueeze(1)
                
                # Forward pass only to get logits/output
                outputs = model(images)
                
                # Get predictions from the maximum value
                _, predicted = torch.max(outputs.data, 1)
                
                # Total number of labels
                total += labels.size(0)
                
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum()
            
            accuracy = 100 * correct / total
            
            # Print Loss
            print('Iteration: {}. Loss: {}. Accuracy: {}'.format(iter, loss.data[0], accuracy))
```

However, the error that I get is:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-c26c43bbc32e> in <module>()
     21 
     22         # Calculate Loss: softmax --> cross entropy loss
---> 23         loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
     24 
     25         # Getting gradients w.r.t. parameters

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in nll_loss(input, target, weight, size_average, ignore_index, reduce, reduction)
   2113                          .format(input.size(0), target.size(0)))
   2114     if dim == 2:
-> 2115         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)
   2116     elif dim == 4:
   2117         ret = torch._C._nn.nll_loss2d(input, target, weight, _Reduction.get_enum(reduction), ignore_index)

RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

My CNN outputs 26 variables and my target variables are also 26D.

How can I change my code so that nn.crossentropyloss() expects a 26D input rather than 1D?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nn.CrossEntropy()(input, target)` expects `input` to be an one-hot vector with size `batchsize X num_classes`, and `target` to be the id of true class with size `batchsize`.

So in short, you can change your target with `target = torch.argmax(target, dim=1)` to have it fit `nn.CrossEntropy()`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to [@Flicic Suo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62678431/10886420)'s answer, you should use `predicted = torch.argmax(output, dim=1)` to get predicted `labels`. Right now you are getting maximum value, what you are after is the class with maximum value.

You would get `0.0` accuracy this way, so `argmax` is correct.